# Auto Start iPad Video

Tags: ipad, itunes, autostart

Is there a way to boot up an iPad to automatically run a video from the Movies App (loaded in from iTunes)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality to do this on the iPad. It might be possible if you "Jailbreak" the iPad, but I wouldn't recommend this.